# html5 video issue - buttons appear as white squares in chrome

Tags: html, video, google-chrome, html5-video

Please review the link: http://www.useboom.com/

The video in home page works fine in other browsers but in chrome the Play and Volume buttons have a white square on top.

The buttons were fine and visible before, we've been deleting unused files and suddenly started to appear this way.

I don't know what is the problem!

Comment: Looks fine to me. Have you tried clearing your cache?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem with Chrome and worked out it is caused by styling "input" without specifying which one exactly i.e.

```
input {
background-color:white;
}
```

Using:

```
#my_div input {
background-color:white;
}
```

solves the problem. Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for that tip. I use `form input { background-color:white; }` now as my videos are never in a form.